# is it possible to create a record in an "unstructured data source with metadata" data store containing only metadata?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is it possible to create a record in the unstructured data source to only contain metadata and not a binary document?
I tried creating such a record and bigquery allows it but the data store created from bigquery gives an error.
Thanks,
Vikas

Given that vertex ai search app can only have one data source, I am looking to store records with only metadata and records with metadata + documents in the same data store. As mentioned earlier the data store creation fails if a record does not have a link to a cloud storage document.